# Is it possible to query rows with multiple counts of appearances in other tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am dealing with a problem. I have to create query that can return me occurrences of a specific key let's call it `keyid` in other tables for each row from my table.

It has to look like this:

```
SELECT 
    parameter1,
    parameter2,
    parameter3,
    parameter4,
    parameter5(count of keyid occurrences in specific table),
    parameter6(count of keyid occurrences in another specific table),
    parameter7(count of keyid occurrences in another specific table),
    parameter8(count of keyid occurrences in another specific table)
```

I have so far made it thus far:

```
SELECT 
    keyid, name, section, address, updatedAt,
    (SELECT COUNT(library.keyid) AS storeCount 
     FROM library 
     LEFT JOIN store ON library.keyid = store.keyid 
     GROUP BY library.keyid) 
FROM 
    library
```

But I get an error:

> ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> SQL state: 21000

Because the subquery wants to return multiple rows that contain count of same `keyid` occurrences for just one row that I take from library. Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: oh sorry, it is postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT keyid, name, section, address, updatedAt,
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM store s
       WHERE l.keyid = s.keyid
      ) AS storeCount
FROM library l;
```

Note that the `GROUP BY` is unnecessary.  But your real problem is that your query is not correlated because `library` is repeated in the subquery.